Run pre-trained LLM model on CPU - ValueError: Expected a cuda device, but got: cpu
I am using a LLM model, CohereForAI/c4ai-command-r-plus-4bit, to do some inference. I have a GPU but it's not powerful enough so I want to use CPU. Below are the example codes and problems.
Code:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel, AutoModelForCausalLM

PRETRAIN_MODEL = 'CohereForAI/c4ai-command-r-plus-4bit'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(PRETRAIN_MODEL)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(PRETRAIN_MODEL, device_map='cpu')

text = "this is an example"
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    embedding = outputs.last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1).squeeze().numpy()
print(embedding.shape)

Error:
ValueError: Expected a cuda device, but got: CPU

Does it mean that the c4ai-command-r-plus-4bit model can only run on GPU? Is there anything I missed to run it on CPU? Thanks!
